# Programatically edited Solution and Project files - but VS now skips Projects during Build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

My situation is that I have quite a few deployment environments; Dev, Integration, QA, UAT, Preproduction, and Live - for two different locations.. which results in 12 separate config transforms/build configurations that need to be set up for every project in every solution for this particular customer.

As you can imagine this is a pain to have to configure by hand, especially for solutions that have been ported across from elsewhere in the codebase and don't already contain these (adding build configurations at a solution level doesn't automatically propagate them to the projects, etc).

Anyway, I've written a small app that automates this by doing the following:
- Edits the solution file (.sln), adding the new build configurations to both the SolutionConfigurationPlatforms, and the ProjectConfigurationPlatforms GlobalSections.
- Edits each project file (.csproj), adding:
  -> a new PropertyGroup for each build configuration
  -> a new config transform element for each build configuration, each DependentUpon the master .config file
- Creates a physical web.XXX-YYY.config file for each build configuration, in each project

I initially had some teething problems with the process, whereby Encoding differed between original and edited versions of the files, etc but this is now fixed. The issue I have is that Visual Studio (2015) refuses to Build/Rebuild/Clean the projects afterwards - instead giving me the "Skipped" message.

I've tried building from the Visual Studio Command Prompt (using msbuild) and this works, an output is successfully created, but still no dice from within VS.

I've tried all sorts of things to resolve this; deleting the .suo file, deleting the bin and obj files, I've even tried deleting all of the edits from one of the project files (and using merge/compare to make sure it's exactly the same as it was pre-edit) and it still gets Skipped.

If I could see some sort of a log to discover the reason for VS skipping the project(s) that would be great, as is all I can go on is the incredibly non-verbose messages in the Output window.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Happy to post code, examples of files pre and post edit, etc...

Comment: I start to lose track of things whenever there's more than _one_ config. What I prefer is to use [Environment variables](http://12factor.net/config). Care to discuss in chat?

Comment: I read your link. It's an interesting point of view, and we certainly are in the "config explosion" position, however there's a couple of negative points that I can see with the env vars idea for us..

1. We're quite heavily invested in config transforms, having taken some time to bring the entire team up to speed with them, it's fairly settled now.

2. The article you link to mentions that env vars mean you don't have to check config into source control, but then env vars live only on the server.. surely you'd need to source control them in some way anyhow?

Comment: Can't really say anything to counter your point #1. With point #2, you're absolutely right. To solve this issue, you might have a bunch of `setup-qa-location-a.cmd`, `setup-production-location-b.cmd`, etc. files checked into your main (or totally separate) repository and then run them as part you deployment process.

Comment: It's an intriguing concept that I'd not really considered before, I can already see the benefit from. We actually don't make any open source software nor do we publically expose any source code/config anyway, quite the opposite, so having config in source control is not a major concern for us.

We have a lot of stuff in config, from db conns, to service urls, unity DI setup, app settings etc. For us to get down to a single config file, we'd have to make a lot of changes (time is a factor), plus I am still keen to figure out what the above issue is due to anyway (project skipping).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Visual Studio `Solution properties` and `Configuration Properties -> Configuration` page in particular. Ensure that the `Build` checkbox is set for each project for all the configurations of your interest. Check all the configurations via the comboboxes on top of the form.

If every project is set to build, try tweaking the MSBuild properties found on 
`Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run`

1. Set the `maximum number of parallel project builds` to **1**. This fixes the inability of VS to correctly suit the build order.
2. Ensure that the `On Run when projects are out of date` is set to `Always build`
3. Set the `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Diagnostic`
4. If you have c++ projects, set the `MSBuild project build log file verbosity` to `Diagnostic`

Execute the build and check the `Output -> Build` window contents.

Try removing the solution user settings. Starting with VS 2015 those are store in a hidden folder named **`.vs`**. Thats right, name starts with a dot. The folder is located near the **`.sln`** file. Just delete the entire `.vs` folder.

Comment: That's one of the first things I did, all configurations are set to build.

Comment: @Detail I appended the further suggested steps

Comment: 3 and 4 were already in place, 1 I didn't think would make a difference as I had unloaded all bar a single project so it's only trying to build one anyway (implemented it nevertheless), and 2 I implemented - although it was set to "prompt" and I would imagine VS would honour this.
Despite the Diagnostic setting on output, VS still just gives me nothing:

------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: XXXXXXXXX ------ 
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========

I would really like to see VS's reasons for skipping, is this not logged anywhere?

Comment: @Detail  Did you try section-by-section comparison of the .sln files one created manually and the one your program creates?

Comment: @Detail Did you try deleting the new `.vs` folder near the `.sln` file?

Comment: @Detail Besides it would be nice if you upload the solution file contents.

Comment: Yes, line by line comparison in WinMerge, plus I even then removed everything that had been added so it matched the pre-edit version - which in WinMerge showed as an exact replica - and yet, build continues to Skip so I'm inclined to think it's not the contents of file that's causing the issue - I can only think that adding Build Configurations by manually inserting them into the .sln and .csproj files is causing VS to mark them as suspect? and is therefore refusing to build... I'm low on ideas now.

Comment: I will try removing the .vs folder, although I'm pretty sure I already tried this. As for deleting the .sln file, I assumed this would be counter productive.. will VS rebuild this from the .csproj files? How do you go about opening the solution with the .sln file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112305/discussion-between-zverev-eugene-and-detail).